How can i cache mongodb queries in NextJs App Router
export async function getArticleBySlug(slug) {
  try {
    await dbConnect();
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error("db error");
  }
  try {
    const article = await Article.findOne({ slug: slug }).select(
      "-updatedAt -__v -_id -image192URL -image296URL -image566URL -image624URL -image80URL"
    );
    if (!article) {
      return null;
    }
    return article;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("db error");
  }
}

I have a pet project blog, now if someone load an article by url my backend connect to mongodb, get the article and return it, it is working with some readed, but with 1000 reader its make 1000 connection. And its make separet connection for all of the articels so if the 1000 reader reads 3 article its 3000 mongodb connection. So can I somehow cache the article after the first load?
I am thinking about creating an array at my file and after the first request i just push in into the array, is it a good sollution?
